# Windows 8 Browser Issue

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, windows-8

I just recently purchases a new laptop with Windows 8 and have been dealing with issues with my browsers. I first started out with Chrome. I installed it, and started using it without any issues. About a week or so later, I begin to start having issues, sometimes the page will load in plain html and sometimes it won't fully load. If I click refresh, it normally works fine then.

Well after this annoyed me enough, I thought it was a chrome issue and moved to firefox. I then downloaded firefox and saw it was doing the same thing, although not all the time. When I just came to stackoverflow.com the page was rendered as plain html. I refreshed the page and it is now working fine.

This seems to be a really weird issue and I believe it may have something to do with scripts. The websites I have most difficultly with are Gmail, Windows Azure, and Quickbooks. On these websites, even when I hit refresh and few times it normally doesn't work. I have to come back at a later time and try again to get it to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I have not tried this in Internet Explorer yet.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am having the same issue.  It is NOT occurring in Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a Samsung, and I bet you do, uninstall the Support Center, clear your cache, and restart. That should solve your problem. It worked for me. There's some conflict between Samsungs support program and how the browsers write to the cache.

Comment: Thank you! You are right, I have a Samsung. This has been driving me nuts for months!